# Update cart to add a line item

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, cart

Can't get cart to update using Ajax in Shopify

I have tried to use a POST request to add a product to the cart when the total price and vendor is equal to a certain vendor.

```
updateCart: function(cart) {
    let total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.items.length; i++){
        total += cart.items[i].price * cart.items[i].quantity;

        if(total >= 7500) && (cart.items[i].vendor == "Ox Tools"){

            jQuery.getJSON(
                '/products/Ox-Pro-Heavy-Duty-Tape-Measure-8M',
                function(product) {

                    alert('The title of this product is ' + product.title);
                }
            );
            jQuery.post(
                '/cart/add.js',
                {
                    quantity: 1,
                    id: 1677113753674
                }
            );
```

Comment: Try to improve formatting

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe should this work?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like incomplete code from here.

Comment: I have tried adding a console.log to see if the script is working fullstop and even the console.log doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize your code better. First off, you have a loop to figure out if you want to add a product or not. Fine... that finishes simply true or false. If it is true, then you can make your query for the desired product. In the response from Shopify, if you get back a product, you would then run the request to add the product to the cart, supplying the id of the product and the quantity.

Comment: How do you see the response from Shopify?